# how to pass NSthread function from one view to another view

Tags: objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am using `NSThread`

Ex:

```
NSThread *driverThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(**pingHomeThread**) object:nil];

[driverThread start]; 

in AppDelegate.m i want to execute  **pingHomeThread** function in another view like myExample.m as 
-(void) pingHomeThread{
}
```

How can i implement this one ?

Comment: Good formatting is your friend.

Comment: Note that updating any UIKit element from other than the main thread may result in delayed updates and unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the target (i don't know want your ** are doing there but they shouldn't be), i.e change

```
NSThread *driverThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(pingHomeThread) object:nil];
```

to

```
NSThread *driverThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:yourOtherView selector:@selector(pingHomeThread) object:nil];
```